# Convert ms word document to svg in C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, svg, ms-word

I want to view a MS Word document in web browser. So i need to convert it to svg format.
How to convert MS Word Document to SVG format using c# or c++ language?which open source library can support this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library DocX that may help.
http://docx.codeplex.com/
Then you can read docx files and write your own converter.

Or you may use Microsoft’s Office interop libraries and convert docx to format such as .pdf or  .html. And it would be easier to convert it to .svg later then.
The code is available at http://cathalscorner.blogspot.jp/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html

Answer (score 0):

I employ Print2Flash library to obtain SVG files directly from Word documents from my ASP.NET web site with c#. I believe that C++ is supported by it as well. You'll need to:

1. Download and install Print2Flash on your server
2. Download Print2Flash SDK and extract ASP.NET and C++ samples from there

Then you just need to follow sample usage instructions. Both files can be got from this download page: http://print2flash.com/download.php

Answer (score 0):

Aspose provides a library for both [C#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/) and [C++](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words.Cpp/) to convert a Word Document to SVG.

- Code Snippet to perform the conversion in C#

  ```
  // The path to the documents directory.
  string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir_QuickStart();

  // Load the document from disk.
  Document doc = new Document(dataDir + "Document.doc");

  dataDir = dataDir + "ConvertDocumentToSVG.svg";

  // Save the document in SVG format.
  doc.Save(dataDir);
  ```
- Code Snippet to perform the conversion in C++

  ```
  // The path to the documents directories.
  System::String inputDataDir = GetInputDataDir_LoadingAndSaving();
  System::String outputDataDir = GetOutputDataDir_LoadingAndSaving();

  // Load the document from disk.
  System::SharedPtr<Document> doc = System::MakeObject<Document>(inputDataDir + u"Document.doc");
  System::String outputPath = outputDataDir + u"ConvertDocumentToSVG.svg";

  // Save the document as SVG.");
  doc->Save(outputPath);
  ```

Please check the documentation for details:

- https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Converting+a+Document
- https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordscpp/Converting+a+Document